Get ILoggerFactory for MongoClientSettings prior to app build
I am using this library's unit of work implementation. Repository.
The library provides a simple approach to MongoDB's unit of work pattern.
I want to leverage MongoDB driver's logging support to log queries.
The library provides an extension method services.AddMongoDbContext<IMongoDbContext, BloggingContext>( for IServiceCollection to add the MongoDbContext, it accepts a MongoClientSettings, in there it requires a ILoggerFactory to setup logging.
The problem is I don't have an ILoggerFactory prior to app build. And the MongoDbContext is added as a services, it can't be added after app build.
This problem is a bit different than other questions about logging in Program.cs before app build. This time, I need the ILoggerFactory for the driver.
The library's how-to:

Usage


First of all, please register the dependencies into the MS Built-In container:

public class BloggingContext : MongoDbContext
{
    public BloggingContext(IMongoClient client, IMongoDatabase database, IMongoDbContextOptions options)
        : base(client, database, options)
    { }
}

// Register the DbContext
services.AddMongoDbContext<IMongoDbContext, BloggingContext>(
    connectionString: Configuration.GetValue<string>("MongoSettings:Blogging:ConnectionString"),
    databaseName: Configuration.GetValue<string>("MongoSettings:Blogging:DatabaseName"),
    setupFluentConfigurationOptions: options => options.ScanningAssemblies = new[] { typeof(BloggingContext).Assembly });

// Register the UnitOfWork
services.AddMongoDbUnitOfWork<BloggingContext>();


After that, use the structure in your code like that:

private readonly IMongoDbUnitOfWork<BloggingContext> _unitOfWork;

// Injection
public BlogsController(IMongoDbUnitOfWork<BloggingContext> unitOfWork)
    => _unitOfWork = unitOfWork ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(unitOfWork), $"{nameof(unitOfWork

public void DeleteBlog()
{
    var repository = _unitOfWork.Repository<Blog>();

    repository.DeleteOne(x => x.Id == id);

    _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
}

Minimal, reproducible example
Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddLogging();

var databaseName = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MongoDB:DatabaseName")?.Get<string>();
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MongoDB:ConnectionString")?.Get<string>();
var databaseSettings = builder
    .Configuration.GetSection("MongoDB:DatabaseSettings")
    ?.Get<MongoDatabaseSettings>();
var clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(connectionString);
clientSettings.LoggingSettings = new LoggingSettings(
    LoggerFactory.Create(loggingBuilder =>
        loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
        .AddConsole()
    ),
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("MongoDB:LoggingMaxDocumentSize").Get<int>()
);


// Register the DbContext
builder.Services.AddMongoDbContext<IMongoDbContext, BloggingContext>(
    clientSettings,
    databaseName,
    databaseSettings,
    fluentConfigurationOptions: new MongoDbFluentConfigurationOptions
    {
        ScanningAssemblies = [typeof(ThEbookContext).Assembly],
    }
);

// Register the UnitOfWork
builder.Services.AddMongoDbUnitOfWork<BloggingContext>();


// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.Run();

BloggingContext.cs
public class BloggingContext(
    IMongoClient client,
    IMongoDatabase database,
    IMongoDbContextOptions options
) : MongoDbContext(client, database, options) { }

BlogModel.cs
public class BlogModel
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string? Id { get; set; } = null!
    [BsonElement("title")]
    [JsonPropertyName("title")]
    public string? Title { get; set; } = null!;
    [BsonElement("richText")]
    [JsonPropertyName("richText")]
    public string? Text { get; set; } = null!;
}

BloggingRepository.cs
public class BloggingRepository: MongoDbRepository<Blog>
{
    protected readonly IMongoCollection<T> _collection;
    protected readonly ILogger<CrudRepository<T>> _logger;
    public BloggingRepository(
        BloggingContext context,
        IOptions<MongoDbSettings> mongoDbSettings,
        ILogger<BloggingRepository> logger
    )
        : base(context)
    {
        _collection = Context.GetCollection<Blog>(
            mongoDbSettings.Value.CollectionNames[typeof(Blog).Name]
        );
        _logger = logger;
    }

BloggingController.cs
[Route("")]
[ApiController]
public class HomeController(BloggingRepository repository, ILogger<HomeController> logger) : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly BloggingRepository _repository = repository;
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger = logger;
    [HttpGet(Name = "HomePage")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Blog>> Get() {
        _logger.LogInformation("Get all blogs");
        await _repository.FindAllAsync();
    }
}

appsettings.json
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Information",
            "MongoDB.Command": "Debug",
            "MongoDB.*": "Error"
        },
        "Console": {
            "FormatterName": "simple",
            "FormatterOptions": {
                "TimestampFormat": "HH:mm:ss "
            }
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "MongoDB": {
        "ConnectionString": "mongodb+srv://redacted:redacted@cluster0.redacted.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0",
        "DatabaseName": "blog",
        "ClientSettings": {},
        "DatabaseSettings": {},
        "LoggingMaxDocumentSize": 100,
        "CollectionNames": {
            "BlogModel": "blog"
        }
    }
}

Blogging.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Data.UnitOfWork" Version="1.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.29.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

What I tried
1. Create a new LoggerFactory
var clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(connectionString);
clientSettings.LoggingSettings = new LoggingSettings(
    LoggerFactory.Create(loggingBuilder =>
        loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
        .AddConsole()
    ),
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("MongoDB:LoggingMaxDocumentSize").Get<int>()
);


Works, but won't have any default setup of builder.Services.AddLogging()

2. Add the MongoDbContext manually
Implementation of AddMongoDbContext

Can't, there are more it does under the hood, and the services it adds are marked internal.

It will be enough if the logger can load all the default settings of builder.Services.AddLogging(). And I won't have to jump to code too much when changing logging settings.
